# How to get default text size of Spinner in Android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

In my application I have custom Spinner (my own class extends Spinner). I need to get default text size of Spinner inside this class. How to get it? I can't find some method for that. May be I can get it from styles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your adapter's drop down view resource is..   If you're using [`simple_spinner_dropdown_item`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_dropdown_item.xml) then it is using this style:

> style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"

Which depends on your system defaults..

Probably easiest would be to get the first item, check if it is an `instanceof TextView` and then, if so, call `getTextSize()` on it.